# Robots.txt syntax -> Can this be done?

Tags: html, robots.txt

When creating a robots.txt, are the following the same?

```
# Slurp
User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /
```

and

`# Slurp User-agent: Slurp Disallow: /`

It seems like for someone disallowing a large number of crawlers at / then a single line notation would be easier to read and realize what is being blocked and what not.

Can one do a single line notation?

Answer (score 4):

No. The [RFC](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt) says:

```
The format logically consists of a non-empty set or records,
separated by blank lines. The records consist of a set of lines of
the form:

  <Field> ":" <value>
```

The formal syntax includes:

```
agentline    = "User-agent:" *space agent  [comment] CRLF
disallowline = "Disallow" ":" *space path [comment] CRLF
allowline    = "Allow" ":" *space rpath [comment] CRLF
extension    = token : *space value [comment] CRLF
```

If you have a Google account and use Google webmaster tools, you can use their [robots.txt checker](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&from=35237&rd=1).

Comment: +1 but to carry over one FYI bit from Badger's response, the leading `#` on the second snippet in the question does comment out the entire line, causing it to do nothing.

Answer (score -3):

Second form do nothing, it's just full-line comment

> The file consists of one or more records separated by one or more
>   blank lines (terminated by CR,CR/NL, or NL). Each record contains
>   lines of the form ":". The
>   field name is case insensitive.
>
> Comments can be included in file using UNIX bourne shell conventions: the '#' character is used to indicate that **preceding
>   space (if any) and the remainder of the line up to the line
>   termination is discarded**. Lines containing only a comment are
>   discarded completely, and therefore do not indicate a record boundary.

```
User-agent: Slurp Disallow: /
```

works the same way as multiline definition

> It seems like for someone disallowing a large number of crawlers at / then a single line notation would be easier to read

It depends. You can use multiline definition and multi-Useragent per URL because

> If more than one User-agent field is present the record describes an
>   identical access policy for more than one robot. At least one field
>   needs to be present per record.

of write oneliner for each crawler

Comment: -1 Quoting a spec is good, but misinterpreting it to get precisely the wrong answer is unhelpful.